# Bash command to parse .env file contains equal (=) sign in values

Tags: bash, sed, grep, environment-variables

I have a `.env` file,

```
# Some variables
USERNAME=user1
PASSWORD=

# Other variables
URL=https://example.com
TOKEN=muDm8qJ6mqM__YX024dk1RXluPnwd-3mxyt1LwLoI4ISiVPA==
```

### Purpose

My purpose is to create one line bash command to print each non-empty variables in `<name> <value>` format, which shall

1. Print one line for each variable with [space] between name and
   value;
2. Ignore comments;
3. Ignore variables with no value;

### Expected output

The expected output is,

```
USERNAME user1
URL https://example.com
TOKEN muDm8qJ6mqM__YX024dk1RXluPnwd-3mxyt1LwLoI4ISiVPA==
```

### Current Solution

My current solution is as following,

```
grep -v '^#' .env | grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' | grep -v '=$' | sed 's/=/ /' | while read -r line; do echo $line; done
```

### Actual output

```
USERNAME user1
URL https://example.com
```

It only prints out the first two lines, the issue with last line is caused by the equal (=) signs in `TOKEN` value.

### Help needed

Anyone can help me to rectify the command? also welcome if there is easier way to achieve the goal.

Comment: `the issue with last line is caused by the equal (=) signs in TOKEN value.` So remove `grep -v '=$'`? What do you think `grep -v '=$'` does?

Comment: @KamilCuk this is to ignore the empty value, e.g. `PASSWORD=`, but it needs to be rectified to handle other situations. That is where I am stuck at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/=\</!d;s/=/ /' input_file
USERNAME user1
URL https://example.com
TOKEN muDm8qJ6mqM__YX024dk1RXluPnwd-3mxyt1LwLoI4ISiVPA==
```

Delete lines that do not match a valid variable i.e have no inpurt after `=`, this will also match blank lines and for your example data, lines with comments as there is no valid variable on the line. Finally, replace the first occurance of the `=` equal character for a space.

Comment: Thanks @HatLess, It works like a charm! Would you mind give some explaination of that regex solution?

Comment: @balun Please check edit

Comment: That is useful. thanks @HatLess

Answer (score 1):

The only way to process *any* environment variable file is to actually interpret it. Various methods for printing out the variable lists are described below.

Various “environment files” are usually designed to be run by POSIX shell to evaluate all the variables. That makes it possible to call external commands, perform calculations etc. when assigning to the variables.

**Do this only is you trust you input file.** Any command can be executed by parsing the file using the script below.

You can source the file (builtin command `.`):

```
. .env
```

After you source it, you can evaluate the variables. If you know what all variables you want to print, use this (for vars `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`)

```
. .env

for var_name in USERNAME PASSWORD
do
    printf "%s %s\n" "$var_name" "${!var_name}"
done
```

If you want to print all the variables that are explicitly specified, use this approach:

```
. .env

grep '^\w+=' | sed 's/=//' | while read var_name
do
    printf "%s %s\n" "$var_name" "${!var_name}"
done
```

But this solution is also not perfect, because the `.env` file can use constructions different from `var_name=value` to assign the vars. Use the `set` command to print all variables.

This prints out **absolutely all** variables. (In reality, the environment file should inherit its variables from the system environment vars, so there is a lot of them.)

```
. .env
printenv | sed 's/=/ /'
```

The `sed` is used to get rid of the equals signs.

**Beware of some dangerous variable values.** The variables can contain even newline character, backspaces and other control characters.

---

There is also a lot of various utilities for printing the variable in a way that allow loading them back to the shell. For example:

`declare -p` or `typeset -p` — prints out `declare` commands to declare all the currently set *shell* variables

`export -p` — the same, but for *environment* variables (that is probably that thing you want)

`set` — prints out all shell variables

Comment: Hi @jiwopene, thanks for help, I got your point, but my purpose is to parse the .env file directly and then push them to other system, so my concern is if I source it on my PC, it may contaminate my PC's envrionment.

Comment: The environment is process-local. There is nothing line “contamination” of the environment. If you want to not modify your current shell variables, run it in a subshell. But if you can't trust the `.env` file source, interpreting the file can be dangerous, because it can execute other commands, but there is no other way to get *precisely the same* values as if it is used.

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71798419).

Answer (score 1):

If the file contains only comments and simple `key=value` lines without `#` chars in strings, you can use this pipeline:

```
sed 's/#.*//' | fgrep = | sed 's/=/ /'
```

Or if you do not want to output empty variables, use this:

```
sed 's/#.*//' | grep =. | sed 's/=/ /'
```

Comment: It outputs `PASSWORD` as well, which shall be ignored because it has no value.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```bash
bash -c 'source <(cat .env | grep USERNAME); echo $USERNAME'
```

why?

- short-ish
- easy to understand with familiar commands
- reusing parsing logic via `source` instead of implementing one

why not?

- key is repeating

  - although wrapping with a function would mitigate that
- maybe you prefer using `sed` or other parsing methods
- maybe you don't want to spawn a new shell `bash -c` for some reason

*inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176874*